# How do I parse a simple grammar and obtain a syntax tree in Emacs lisp?

Tags: syntax, semantic-mode, parsing, smie

How can I construct a parse tree from a string and a simple grammar? Semantic seems very tricky, and SMIE does not seem to produce a parse tree.

Here's an example, assuming a language that looks like this:

```
BLAH [ FOO "aaa"; "bbb" | BAR [ "ccc" | "ddd" ] ]
```

How can I simply transform that string into the following sexp, or something close?

```el
(seq (ident "BLAH")
     (choice (cons (seq (ident "FOO") (str "aaa"))
                   (seq (str "bbb")))
             (seq  (ident "BAR")
                   (choice (seq (str "ccc")) (seq (str "ddd"))))))
```

(essentially there are sequences `seq` (no delimiters), grouping choices `choice` (`[]`), strings `""`, identifiers `ident` (capitals), and delimited sequences `cons` (`;`-delimited))

Comment: Semantic is the thing that properly produces a language parse tree in Emacs. See [Adding support for a new language](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/addlang.shtml) (a bit outdated, but a good starting point if you put a bit of effort). Essentially, all you need is supplied a language grammar file. Or, you can reinvent the lexing/parsing process and manually produce the parse tree.

Comment: @TuDo Is there a semantic function that yields a full parse tree?

Comment: Yes, assume that the current major mode is already supported by Semantic (which means a grammar file was written and compiled for it), then you use `(semantic-fetch-tags)` to get the tree. Try it in C/C++ mode or Emacs Lisp mode. Here is an example of using manipulating the tags in the function [srefactor--fetch-candidates-helper](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor/blob/master/srefactor.el#L1332) of my package `srefactor` to produce [a navigation tree](http://i.imgur.com/ewJWwt9.gifv).

Comment: @TuDo Interesting. That always returns `nil` for me, even after `semantic-force-refresh`.

Comment: You must run `(semantic-default-elisp-setup)` and then enable Semantic with `(semantic-mode 1)` before fetching tags.

Comment: If you run `semantic-fetch-tags` in C/C++, you only need to enable `semantic-mode`.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/blob/master/lisp/tablist-filter.el) I've used wisent (semantic's parser) to parse a simple grammar.

Comment: Published some library which might be helpful https://github.com/andreas-roehler/werkstatt/blob/master/misc/transform.el Please open issues there maybe.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://github.com/cute-jumper/parsec.el (A parser-combinator library)